# YII: How to register a yiiwheels widget assets without calling the widget

Tags: php, yii, assets, yii-extensions, yii-widgets

I use Yiiwheels. I want to change a combo box to select 2 widget, but the pertinent assets are not loaded yet. The ugly solution is creating a dummy select2 element in a hidden span, so assets are loaded automatically. but is there any better way to do that, I mean a function to load assets of a widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are looking for is the `registerClientScript()` function in `WhSelect2` widget class in Yiiwheels.

While creating an empty widget is the easiest way to register the script you can alternatively call it directly with something like this

```
<?php Yii::import('yiiwheels.widgets.select2.WhSelect2');
    $w = new WhSelect2(); 
    $w->registerClientScript();
?>
```

The `registerClientScript()` function is called in `init()`call during widget creation, the following is operations executed by this function See [WhSelect2 on github](https://github.com/2amigos/yiiwheels/blob/master/widgets/select2/WhSelect2.php) for the full code

```
   /**
    * Registers required client script for bootstrap select2. It is not used through bootstrap->registerPlugin
    * in order to attach events if any
    */
    public function registerClientScript()
    {
        /* publish assets dir */
        $path = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'assets';
        $assetsUrl = $this->getAssetsUrl($path);

        /* @var $cs CClientScript */
        $cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();

        $cs->registerCssFile($assetsUrl . '/css/select2.css');
        $cs->registerScriptFile($assetsUrl . '/js/select2.js');


        if ($this->language) {
            $cs->registerScriptFile(
                $assetsUrl . '/js/locale/select2_locale_' . $this->language . '.js',
                CClientScript::POS_END
            );
        }

        /* initialize plugin */
        $selector = '#' . TbArray::getValue('id', $this->htmlOptions, $this->getId());

        $this->getApi()->registerPlugin('select2', $selector, $this->pluginOptions, CClientScript::POS_READY);
        $this->getApi()->registerEvents($selector, $this->events, CClientScript::POS_READY);
    }
```